# How to update a dataframe with dictionary values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has a mapping of every unique key to every unique value. I also have a dataframe that has a column that contains all of these keys (possibly numerous times). A column adjacent to the column of keys has values that need to be replaced by value associated with the key in the other column.

I have tried using iloc, where, and update, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                 '2': ["alpha", 2.34, 0, 4.1234],
                  '3': ["bravo", 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '4': ["charlie", 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '5': ["delta", 20.123, 3.123123, 0]},

                 index=['1', '2', '3', '4'])
```

and the dictionary

```
d = {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 5, 'D': 10}
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                 '2': ["2", "3", "5", "10"],
                  '3': [7, 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '4': [9, 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
                   '5': [11, 20.123, 3.123123, 0]},

                 index=['1', '2', '3', '4'])
```

This is the expected output from the merge.

Comment: In your output, it looks like the entire first row is replaced which doesn't correlate with the explanation provided.

Comment: Your code examples and description are inconsistent.  Based on your description, I would have expected a new column with the contents: `[ 2, 3, 5, 10]`.

Comment: @suvayu Sorry copied the wrong dataframe. Updated.

Comment: how  does '2': ["alpha", 2.34, 0, 4.1234]   this transforms to  '2': ["2", "3", "5", "10"]. Am i missing something here or inconsistent explanation .

Comment: @vrana95, I am simply asking for a dictionary to be used to update the values of the corresponding column. If dtypes and placeholder values make a huge difference here in the example I can change them but the base premise remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "1": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        "2": ["alpha", 2.34, 0, 4.1234],
        "3": ["bravo", 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
        "4": ["charlie", 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
        "5": ["delta", 20.123, 3.123123, 0],
    },
    index=["1", "2", "3", "4"],
)
```

Reset the index to column `1`

```
df = df.set_index("1")
```

Use a `Series` instead of a dictionary; they are more or less similar.  Note I also name it to `"2"` as we want to replace column `2`.

```
d = pd.Series({"A": 2, "B": 3, "C": 5, "D": 10}, name="2")
```

You may now join with either of the two ways shown below.  The first retains the old column with the column name suffixed as `_old`, the second simply drops it.

```
df = df.join(d, lsuffix="_old")
df = df[["3", "4", "5"]].join(d)
```

If you want the numerical index back, you could reset the index again:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
```

Here's the output with the first way of joining:

```
   1   2_old        3        4        5   2
0  A   alpha    bravo  charlie    delta   2
1  B    2.34   20.123   20.123   20.123   3
2  C       0  3.12312  3.12312  3.12312   5
3  D  4.1234        0        0        0  10
```

Please note, even though your example data does not have repeated values in `1`, the above should still work.

In your expected results dataframe you show the new column has strings instead of integers.  If that's your expectation, then you would need to supply strings when you create the `Series` object before the join.

```
d = pd.Series({"A": "2", "B": "3", "C": "5", "D": "10"}, name="2")
```

Or you could change it after the fact like this:

```
df["2"] = df["2"].astype("str")
```

**Edit:** Since the OP was looking for a more concise way to achieve this, a variation could be:

```
d = pd.Series({"A": "2", "B": "3", "C": "5", "D": "10"}, name="2")
df = df.join(d, on="1", lsuffix="_old")
```

**Edit 2:** As suggested by the OP, another option is to use `Series.map`:

```
d = {"A": "2", "B": "3", "C": "5", "D": "10"}
df["2"] = df["1"].map(d)
```

**Edit 3:** I did a quick performance test; the `Series.map` method is significantly faster.

```
In [34]: %timeit df.join(d, on="1", lsuffix="_old")                        
1.3 ms ± 58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [35]: %timeit df["1"].map(d)      
214 µs ± 3.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Setting the index and joining, improves the performance of the `join` method by a bit:

```
In [40]: foo = df.set_index("1")     
In [41]: %timeit foo.join(d, lsuffix="_old")                               
818 µs ± 25.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: So ideally you don't have to deal with a dictionary and both objects are dataframes?

Comment: This should boil down to some kind of simple merge/join, this solution seems too complicated.

Comment: It **is** a join!  I added one step to set the index so that the join is simpler, and converted the `dict` to a `Series` so that a join is possible.  The third step is the join itself, I don't know how much simpler you want it to be.  You can remove the `set_index` step, and add `on="2"` as an argument to join.  That reduces it to two steps.

Comment: @rye_bread please check the edit, I also fixed the typo I made in the above comment

Comment: ```df["2"] = df["1"].map(d)``` seems to work and be a lot simpler?

Comment: @rye_bread I really don't understand what you mean by simpler. To me, it's lines of code.  In terms of that there's no difference.  If the `Series.map` way suits you better, use that.  There are always multiple ways to achieve something, specially in `pandas`.  I'll include it in my answer for completeness.

Comment: @rye_bread I added a few performance comparisons.  Your suggestion is quite a bit faster. Although the gap could narrow a bit, because in my performance test I'm not counting for reallocating the column whereas that is part of the join.